# Using service principal to access blob storage from Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I followed [Access an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account directly with OAuth 2.0 using the Service Principal](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html#access-an-adls-account-directly-with-oauth-2-0-using-the-service-principal) and want to achieve the same but with blob storage general purpose v2 (with hierarchical fs disabled). Is it possible to get this working, or authenticating using access key or SAS is the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is not possible as of now. OAuth Bearer Token is supported for Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (with the hierarchical namespace enabled when creating the storage account). To access Azure Data Lake Store Gen2 the [ABFS-driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver) is used:

```
abfss://<your-file-system-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

To access the Blob Storage you use WASB:

```
wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net
```

only supporting token based access.

Comment: Why do the docs sound like that Blob Storage + OAuth 2.0 with a service principle should be possible (but it's not):

"Access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 **or Blob Storage using OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal**"

[link](https://docs.databricks.com/storage/azure-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Blob Storage using OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal will work only for ADLS Gen2 with Hierarchical namespace enable. It looks like even if your storage shows ADLSv2 but Hierarchical namespace is disable it will not allow for ABFS with SP.

If you use normal Azure storage ( without Hierarchical namespace enable) only WASB should be possible but Service Principal doesn’t work- only supporting token based access.

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the previous answer